# MYSQL: Avoiding cartesian product of repeating records when self-joining

Tags: mysql, identifier, self-join, cartesian-product

**There are two tables: table A and table B. They have the same columns and the data is practically identical**. They both have auto-incremented IDs, the only difference between the two is that they have different IDs for the same records.

**Among the columns, there is an IDENTIFIER column which is not unique**, i.e. there are (very few) records with the same IDENTIFIER in both tables.

Now, in order to find a correspondence between the IDs of table A and the IDs of table B, **I have to join these two tables** (for all purposes it's a self-join) on the IDENTIFIER column, something like:

```
SELECT A.ID, B.ID
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.IDENTIFIER = B.IDENTIFIER
```

**But, being IDENTIFIER non-unique, this generates every possible combination of the repeating values of IDENTIFIER, I don't want that.**

Ideally, I would like to **generate an one to one association between IDs that have repeating IDENTIFIER values**, based on their order. For example, supposing that there are six records with different ID and the same IDENTIFIER value in table A (and thus in table B):

```
A                                 B
IDENTIFIER:'ident105', ID:10  ->  IDENTIFIER:'ident105', ID:3
IDENTIFIER:'ident105', ID:20  ->  IDENTIFIER:'ident105', ID:400
IDENTIFIER:'ident105', ID:23  ->  IDENTIFIER:'ident105', ID:420
IDENTIFIER:'ident105', ID:100 ->  IDENTIFIER:'ident105', ID:512
IDENTIFIER:'ident105', ID:120 ->  IDENTIFIER:'ident105', ID:513
IDENTIFIER:'ident105', ID:300 ->  IDENTIFIER:'ident105', ID:798
```

That would be ideal.
Anyway, a way to generate a one to one association regardless of the order of the IDs would still be ok (but not preferred).

Thanks for your time,

Silvio

Comment: +1 since you have me stumped...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a_numbered.id, a_numbered.identifier, b_numbered.id from 
(
select a.*,
       case 
          when @identifier = a.identifier then @rownum := @rownum + 1
          else @rownum := 1
       end as rn,
       @identifier := a.identifier
  from a
  join (select @rownum := 0, @identifier := null) r
order by a.identifier

) a_numbered join (
select b.*,
       case 
          when @identifier = b.identifier then @rownum := @rownum + 1
          else @rownum := 1
       end as rn,
       @identifier := b.identifier
  from b
  join (select @rownum := 0, @identifier := null) r
order by b.identifier

) b_numbered 
on a_numbered.rn=b_numbered.rn and a_numbered.identifier=b_numbered.identifier
```